# What's the difference between "to lie in" and "to sleep in"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What's the difference between "to lie in" and "to sleep in"?

And could you correct the following sentence please:

"I wanted to turn off my mobile telefone not to be called next morning, but I forgot to do that and my friend called me so early, that my plan to sleep/lie in failed"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you studying the English spoken in a particular region, such as American English or British English?

Comment: I am studying general British English

Answer (score 2):

In Britain 'to lie in' means deliberately to get up later than usual; e.g. 'I generally lie in at week-ends'.

'To sleep in' means the same thing as to 'oversleep' e.g. ' I overslept and was late for work.' or 'I slept in, and missed the train'.

In Norfolk dialect they speak of 'to lay late', meaning to oversleep. They say 'lay' in Norfolk when they mean 'lie'.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to turn off my mobile telefone **so as** not to be called next morning, but I forgot to do **it** and my friend called me so early, that my plan to **sleep long** failed.

Comment: Sleep long? That's not a phrase I've ever used or even heard before.

Comment: I think this expression varies greatly according to local dialect in the UK. See my Norfolk example above.

Answer (score 0):

Here in Ireland (and also in the UK), I would say that *lie in* is by far the more normal term, but *sleep in* could also be used. A *lie in* is intentional, or at least semi-intentional. This is one of the places where [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22lie%20in%22,%22sleep%20in%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%22%20lie%20in%20%22;,c0;.t1;,%22%20sleep%20in%20%22;,c0) is unhelpful: it will include all references for *lie in bed* and *sleep in a hotel* and all sorts of similar constructs, not just *lie in* and *sleep in* as phrasal verbs.

The other variant is *to sleep it out*, which means oversleeping unintentionally. It’s possible that this is a phrase used [only in Ireland](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32731/sleep-in-versus-sleep-out).

Comment: This expression, I feel sure, varies greatly according to regional dialect in the UK. See my Norfolk example above.

Comment: Elsewhere in the Anglosphere, _sleep it out_ refers to sleeping as long as you need to make your hangover go away.